# In a production system, do you configure your logging in appsettings or in code?

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

In ASP.NET Core we can configure logging in the **appsettings.json** file or in **code**.

I am looking for **pros/cons** on what to choose for a modern ASP.NET Core service.

Putting it in **appsettings.json** could be convenient if you want to be able to tweak the logging without redeploying your application. However, when we move to immutable infrastructure, containers that you can't login to, then I guess the possibility to tweak appsettings.json is no longer a valid argument.

Where/how would you configure logging if you were developing a new application today?

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer:

1. Try to google environment variables in asp.net core.
2. A fast lightweight NOSQL DB, where you can store your app settings and create a lightweight wrapper service to query them.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that , or I can use things like Azure key vault. But those are mostly for simpler values as connection strings..., what I am looking for how people today configure their logging system, externally, in appsettings/AKV or in code? The serilog object for example can get pretty big, see  https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration